# How to properly type an array of generic mixed types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-decorator

I am working on a decorator that will apply an array of mixins to a class using a combination of the recommended and alternative patterns described in the TS Handbook.  Additionally, I would like these mixins to accept parameters and for the decorator to validate them.  I am getting close, but I can't seem to get this working perfectly.  The first item works fine, but then it seems to dictate the only accepted shape and the rest of the items are marked invalid.  Is this something that can be currently accomplished with TypeScript?

```
type IConstructor = new ( ...args: any[]) => any;

type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [ any, ...infer I ] ? I : never;

type IClassMixin = ( baseClass: IConstructor, ...args: any[]) => any;

type IClassMixinWithParamsTuple<T extends IClassMixin> = [ T, ...Tail<Parameters<T>> ]

function applyMixins<K extends IClassMixin>( mixins: Array<IClassMixinWithParamsTuple<K>> ) {
    return <T extends IConstructor>( derivedCtor: T ) => {
        for ( let i = 0; i < mixins.length; i++ ) {
            const mixin = mixins[i];
            if ( Array.isArray( mixin )) {
                const [ mx, ...args ] = mixin;
                derivedCtor = mx( derivedCtor, ...args );
            }
        }

        return derivedCtor;
    };
}


interface Jump {
  jump(): void;
}

function Jump( base: IConstructor, jumpHeight: number ) {
  return class extends base {
    #jumpHeight: number = jumpHeight;
    jump() {}
  }
}


interface Duck {
  duck(): void;
}

function Duck( base: IConstructor ) {
  return class extends base {
    duck() {}
  }
}
 

interface Fight {
  fight(): void;
}

function Fight( base: IConstructor, attackName: string ) {
  return class extends base {
    #attackName: string = attackName;
    fight() {}
  }
}


interface Player extends Jump, Duck, Fight {}

@applyMixins([
  [ Fight, 'Rocket Punch' ],
  [ Jump, 12345 ],
  [ Duck ],
])
class Player {
  combo() {
    this.jump();
    this.duck();
    this.fight();
  }
}
```

**BONUS:** Is it possible to allow a more flexible decorator input?  I would like to accept a single mixin, or an array of maybe mixin or tuple.

```
function applyMixins<K extends IClassMixin>( mixins: K | Array<K | IClassMixinWithParamsTuple<K>> ) { ... }

@applyMixins([
  Duck,
  [ Fight, 'Rocket Punch' ],
  [ Jump, 12345 ],
])
class Fighter { ... }

@applyMixins([Duck, Jump])
class Pacifist { ... }

@applyMixins(Duck)
class Coward { ... }
```